# Is the size of maximum matching in vertex transitive 3-uniform hyper-graph on $n$ vertices always $\Omega(n)$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, finite-groups, hypergraph, matching-theory

What is the best known lower bound on the size of the maximum matching in a vertex transitive $3$-uniform hyper-graph?